# Negative focal length in Camera Calibration Matrix

Tags: computer-vision

While trying to work with the [ICL_NUIM](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ahanda/VaFRIC/iclnuim.html) dataset I have ran into some issues. The camera calibration provided on the site has the following values:

```
481.20,  0,      319.50

0,      -480.00, 239.50

0,       0,      1
```

where:

```
fx = 481.20
fy = -480.00
cu = 319.50
cv = 239.50
```

I am struggling to intuitively understand how the fy can have a negative value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical effect is simply that the image is vertically inverted.
This is the equivalent of the image as appears on the classical pinhole model, in the back plane of the camera box.  In that case both the fx,fy would be negative, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, I have since found a [paper](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ahanda/VaFRIC/icra2014.pdf) describing the camera calibration matrix. It basically preforms a conversion from right hand coordinates to left hand coordinates.